# Can you set the value for the selecteddatakey of a gridview from codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Currently I am highlighting the rows on my gridview through code behind. The problem is when I inserted a new data through formview, I put the highlight on the new data but if you click edit or delete if would go for either the first data on the grid if you have not selected anything yet or the last data you have selected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN Documentation, [GridView.SelectedDataKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selecteddatakey.aspx) its a read only property.

You may want to check the documentation for [GridView.SelectedPersistedKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedpersisteddatakey.aspx) which is settable.